# Magento - add to cart and FE user login not working

Tags: magento

im running Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

I had some bug in the backend - one file was missing (possible error on upload..), so i uploaded all the /app folder again to web server.

Now add to cart button AND fe user login doesn't work.. i checked and magento doesn't create any session variables (probably it should..) I have installed EU Cookie law plugin and its shown every time (it should only first time, when coming to page).

There is no entry in error log or anything else. What can i do, it looks small error but where to look for?

The page is: http://collection69.com/

Thank you very much for help!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has tahe same problem, at the end was some server mis-configuration about sessions..
So try another server ;)